# Python: simplifying nested FOR loop?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, nested

I am wondering if there is a way to simplify the nested loop below. The difficulty is that the iterator for each loop depends on things from the previous loops. Here is the code:

```
# Find the number of combinations summing to 200 using the given list of coin

coin=[200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]

total=[200,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
# total[j] is the remaining sum after using the first (j-1) types of coin
# as specified by i below

count=0
# count the number of combinations

for i in range(int(total[0]/coin[0])+1):
    total[1]=total[0]-i*coin[0]
    for i in range(int(total[1]/coin[1])+1):
      total[2]=total[1]-i*coin[1]
      for i in range(int(total[2]/coin[2])+1):
          total[3]=total[2]-i*coin[2]
          for i in range(int(total[3]/coin[3])+1):
              total[4]=total[3]-i*coin[3]
              for i in range(int(total[4]/coin[4])+1):
                  total[5]=total[4]-i*coin[4]
                  for i in range(int(total[5]/coin[5])+1):
                      total[6]=total[5]-i*coin[5]
                      for i in range(int(total[6]/coin[6])+1):
                          total[7]=total[6]-i*coin[6]
                          count+=1

print count
```

Comment: See also ["Recursively find all coin combinations that produces a specified amount"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9815077/90527), ["How to ask and answer homework questions?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10811/).

Comment: your problem should be getting a smarter algorithm, not simplifying the nested loops

Comment: @outis - well if it is homework, I'm a bit annoyed with myself, but there's some effort here, and I guess a constraints library might be a bit tricky anyway...

Comment: it's 31 from project euler. Yes, if it asks for 2000 instead of 200, this is probably too slow, but I am just trying to translate my thoughts into a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can get rid of all the int casting.  An int/int is still an int in python ie integer division.
2. it looks like Recursion would clean this up nicly

   ```
   count  = 0
   coin=[200,100,50,20,10,5,2,1]
   total=[200,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]

   def func(i):
       global count,total,coin
       for x in range(total[i-1]/coin[i-1]+1):
           total[i]=total[i-1]-x*coin[i-1]
           if (i == 7):
               count += 1
           else:
               func(i+1)
   ```

   func(1)
   print count

Comment: `/` became floating division in Python3. It's better to use `//` if you want the int division as that works the same in Python2 and Python3

Comment: @gnibbler ahhh, go to know, I have avoided python 3 because I was annoyed at how much has changed.  But at least now I can avoid sounding like an a** :-)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend looking at http://labix.org/python-constraint which is a Python constraint library. One of its example files is actually permutations of coinage to reach a specific amount, and it all handles it for you once you specify the rules.

Comment: [coins.py](http://codespeak.net/svn/user/niemeyer/constraint/trunk/examples/coins/coins.py)

Comment: though it enumerates all solution that is less effective than just count them using e.g., dynamic programming

Comment: I don't disagree - although I prefer generic solutions, then use other solutions if I experience bottleneck for a specific task

Comment: That's nice to know for more complicated problems, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
combinations = set()
for i in range(len(coins)):
  combinations = combinations | set(for x in itertools.combinations(coins, i) if sum(x) == 200)
print len(combinations)
```

It's a little slow, but it should work.