# How to reduce the complexity of several for loops in python

Tags: python

I have the following function

```
import requests

children_dict = {}
def get_list_of_children(base_url, username, password, folder="1"):
    token = get_token()
    url = f"{base_url}/unix/repo/folders/{folder}/list"
    json = requests_json(url,token)
    for obj in json["list"]:
        if obj['name'] == 'MainFolder':
            folderId = obj['id']
            url_parent = f"{base_url}/unix/repo/folders/{folderId}/list"
            json_parent = requests_json(url_parent,token)
            for obj_child in json_parent['list']:
                if obj_child['folder'] == True:
                    folder_grand_child_id = obj_child['id']
                    url_grand_child = f"{base_url}/unix/repo/folders/{folder_grand_child_id}/list"
                    json_grand_child = requests_json(url_grand_child,token)
                    for obj_grand_child in json_grand_child["list"]:
                        if obj_grand_child['name'] == 'SubFolder':
                            folder_grand_grand_child = obj_grand_child['id']
                            url_grand_grand_child = f"{base_url}/unix/repo/folders/{folder_grand_grand_child}/list"
                            json_grand_grand_child = requests_json(url_grand_grand_child,token)
                            for obj_grand_grand_child in json_grand_grand_child["list"]:
                                if obj_grand_grand_child['name'] == 'MainTasks':
                                    folder_grand_grand_grand_child = obj_grand_grand_child['id']
                                    url_grand_grand_grand_child = f"{base_url}/unix/repo/folders/{folder_grand_grand_grand_child}/list"
                                    json_grand_grand_grand_child = requests_json(url_grand_grand_grand_child,token)
                                    for obj_grand_grand_grand_child in json_grand_grand_grand_child["list"]:
                                        children_dict[[obj_grand_grand_grand_child['id']] = obj_grand_grand_grand_child['name']
                                    
                            

        
        
    
    return children_dict
```

What i am trying to accomplish here is to make repeated api calls to traverse through http folder structure to get the list of files in the last directory
The function works as intended but sonarlint is through the below error

`Refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 45 to the 15 allowed. [+9 locations]sonarlint(python:S3776)`

is there is a better way to handle this function ?

can anyone refactor this, pointing me in the right direct will do

Comment: maybe you need xpath

Comment: its api calls and i am not using web elements

Comment: Maybe you can use List Comprehensions

Comment: or at least you can split them to short functions, with meaningful names.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129093/python-simplifying-nested-for-loop) is useful to you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a complete solution, but to answer your question "how can I simplify this" more generally, you need to look for repeated patterns in your code and generalize them into a function.  Perhaps it's a function you can call recursively, or in a loop.  For example, in that deeply-nested statement of yours it's just the same pattern over and over again like:

```py
    url = f"{base_url}/unix/repo/folders/{folder}/list"
    json = requests_json(url,token)
    for obj in json["list"]:
        if obj['name'] == '<some folder name>':
            folderId = obj['id']
            # ...repeat...
```

So try generalizing this into a loop, maybe, like:

```py
url_format = "{base_url}/unix/repo/folders/{folder_id}/list"
folder_hierarchy = ['MainFolder', 'SubFolder', 'MainTasks']
folder_id = '1'  # this was the argument passed to your function
for subfolder in folder_hierarchy:
    url = url_format.format(base_url=base_url, folder_id=folder_id)
    folder_json = requests_json(url, token)
    for obj in folder_json['list']:
        if obj['name'] == subfolder:
            folder_id = obj['id']
            break
    # Now the pattern repeats for the next level of the hierarchy but
    # starting with the new folder_id
```

This is just schematic and you may need to generalize further, but it's one idea.

If your goal is to traverse a more complicated hierarchy you might want to look into tree-traversal algorithms.

Comment: in this case, looks like DFS might be helpful

Comment: Indeed, my answer is very over-simplified just to give a general idea of how to generalize something like this.  In reality OP would probably like to take the same idea and implement it as a depth-first traveral.  This could be done with a slight modification that uses `folder_hierarchy` like a stack.

Answer (score 3):

There's plenty of repeating code. Once you identify the repeating patterns, you can extract them to the classes and functions. In particular, I find it useful to isolate all the web API logic from the rest of the code:

```
class Client:
    def __init__(self, base_url, token):
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.token = token

    def list_folder(self, folder_id):
      return request_json(
          f'{self.base_url}/unix/repo/folders/{folder_id}/list', self.token
      )['list']

    def get_subfolders(self, parent_id=1):
        return [c for c in self.list_folder(parent_id) if c['folder']]

    def get_subfolder(self, parent_id, name):
        children = self.list_folder(parent_id)
        for child in children:
            if child['name'] == name:
                return child
        return None

    def resolve_path(self, path, root_id=1):
        parent_id = root_id
        for p in path:
            current = self.get_subfolder(parent_id, p)
            if not current:
                return None
            parent_id = current['id']

        return current
```

Now you can use the class above to simplify the main code:

```
client = Client(base_url, token)
for folder in client.get_subfolders():
    child = client.resolve_path(folder['id'], ('SubFolder', 'MainTasks'))
    if child:
       # do the rest of the stuff
```

The code above is not guaranteed to work as is, just an illustration of the idea.

Answer (score 2):

I can't really test it, but I'd make it like the following in order to easily build many levels of repeating code.

```
class NestedProcessing:
    def __init__(self, base_url):
        self.base_url = base_url
        self.token = get_token()
        self.obj_predicates = []
        
    def next_level_predicate(self, obj_predicate):
        self.obj_predicates.append(obj_predicate)
        return self
        
    def final_action(self, obj_action):
        self.obj_action = obj_action
        return self
        
    def process(self, first_folder_id):
        self.process_level(0, first_folder_id)
                    
    def process_level(self, index, folder_id):
        obj_is_good = self.obj_predicates[index]
        url = f"{self.base_url}/unix/repo/folders/{folder_id}/list"
        json = requests_json(url, self.token)
        for obj in json["list"]:
            if index == len(self.obj_predicates) - 1: # last level
                self.obj_action(obj)
            elif obj_is_good(obj):
                self.process_level(index + 1, obj['id'])

        

def get_list_of_children(base_url, username, password, folder="1"):
    children_dict = {}
    NestedProcessing(base_url)
        .next_level_predicate(lambda obj: obj['name'] == 'MainFolder')
        .next_level_predicate(lambda obj: obj['folder'] == True)
        .next_level_predicate(lambda obj: obj['name'] == 'SubFolder')
        .next_level_predicate(lambda obj: obj['name'] == 'MainTasks')
        .final_action(lambda obj, storage=children_dict: storage.update({obj['id']: obj['name']})
        .process(folder)
    return children_dict
```

Comment: can you check this line `def process(self, first_folder_id):
        self.process_level(index=0, first_folder_id)` i am getting error `Positional argument cannot appear after keyword arguments`

Comment: Yeah sure, just remove `index=` part, let it be `self.process_level(0, first_folder_id)`

Comment: `NameError: name 'process_level' is not defined` can you look at this ?

Comment: replace with `self.process_level`

Comment: i am getting error `KeyError: '221037'` in the lambda statement,

Comment: is this specific to the api call or something you can do to fix the logic ?

Comment: It sounds strange, but try to change last lambda `.final_action(lambda obj, storage=children_dict: storage.update({obj['id']: obj['name']})`. But it might not work anyway

Comment: Thanks for your help Alexey, as i am short on time i have used the for loop suggested by @iguananaut